# How to write functions in terms of the Fox H-function?

Tags: special-functions, complex-integration

I wonder whether there is some general algorithm or strategy to try to write some general function in terms of the H-function.

For instance, consider the following function.
$$
f(x)=\alpha^{k x} \frac{x^{\beta}}{[\Gamma(x)]^{n}},
$$
where $\alpha\beta\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and $k,n\in \mathbb{N}^+$. I am trying to obtain some H-function of the form
$$
f(x)=x^{\beta}\times H(g(x)),
$$
where $H$ is the Fox H-function and $g(x)$ some function of $x$. I would appreciate any directions that could help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mathematica has a built in function specially for this purpose, `FoxHReduce`, but it fails to produce a result even for the reciprocal Gamma function on its own.

Comment: Perhaps, we could find a series expansion of the parts of the function, then trying to adapt to the generalized hypergeometric function, which is related with the h-functions. However, I am sure about the reciprocal gamma function.